# Dropping all collections in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have searched the api, but can't find anything relating to the dropping of a database without iterating through the collections manually.

Is there a simpler way of calling `db.dropDatabase()` through mongoengine? Its not a big deal to iterate through just wanted a simpler way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about doing it this way?

```
from mongoengine import connect

db = connect('test')
db.drop_database('test')
```

Alternatively, you can get connection object from `_get_db()` method:

```
from mongoengine import connect
from mongoengine.connection import _get_db

connect('test')

db = _get_db()
db.connection.drop_database('test')
```